# Relative control position in .NET / Visual Studio Editor

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, controls, anchor

I am editing custom control in control editor of Visual Studio 2008

My custom control has datagrid view on the left and buttons on the right. I want my control when resized to keep button size constant always and keep them aligned to *right* border and only my datagrid control to be resized so that horizontal distances between borders and control remained the same. (See illustration below) I remember there was some feature in WinForms and Editor like anchors or other that would me to do that automatically. I just cannot find it in MSVS.

```
==============================
| ****************  *button*  |
| * datagridview *  *button*  |
| *              *  *button*  |
| ****************            |
==============================


=================================
| *******************  *button*  |
| * datagridview    *  *button*  |
| *                 *  *button*  |
| *******************            |
================================
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anchor the buttons right, top. Then anchor the datagrid left, right and top.

That should do it.

Have a look at

[Control.Anchor Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx)

and

[Form Anchor](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/GUI-Windows-Form/FormAnchor.htm)

Comment: Is there some WISIWIG interface in editor? button, check box or mouse trick

Comment: If you are looking for the property, it is in the property grid called *Anchor*. When you click it, it will show a dropdown from where you can select the anchors.